# Inner Join or other examples for comparison in large tables

Tags: sql, oracle, join

I have two massive tables in **Oracle** which have outputs from two jobs. I have one column which has the same data in both the tables. I need a query to compare these two tables based on this common field and list the differences from both the tables on other columns.

I tried the following example of `inner join` but getting this error:

> missing right parenthesis

.

```
SELECT
       table1.column1,
       table2.column2, 
      (CASE WHEN (table1.column1 = table2.column2 THEN 'No change' ELSE 'Change DETECTED' END)) AS Difference
FROM
table1 INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.id=table2.id
```

Comment: please test this query and feedback me : `SELECT
       table1.column1,
       table2.column2, 
       CASE WHEN (table1.column1 = table2.column2) THEN 'No change' ELSE 'Change DETECTED' END AS Difference
FROM
table1 INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.id=table2.id`

Comment: The inner parentheses in the `case` are not correct.

Answer (score 2):

Remove the parentheses from the `CASE` part:

```
SELECT table1.column1,
       table2.column2,
       CASE
          WHEN table1.column1 = table2.column2 THEN 'No change'
          ELSE 'Change DETECTED'
       END
          AS Difference
  FROM table1 INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.id = table2.id
```

Answer (score 1):

Modify your query like this:

```
    SELECT table1.column1
         , table2.column2
         , CASE WHEN table1.column1 = table2.column2 
                THEN 'No change' 
                ELSE 'Change DETECTED' END AS Difference 
      FROM table1 INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.id = table2.id
```

Comment: thanks this worked. Unfortunately the column which i thought was an unique column, has dupes in subsequent rows in few cases. And the field which i am comparing is a date field which results in differences which are not true differences. Is there a way to sort the data across both the tables so that I get only the 'true' differences?

Comment: what means of 'true' differences in your data?

Comment: please give me example data without any data i haven't any sense to solve your problem

Comment: okay this is what i have, lets say  - Table 1 has three columns -> id, date, address. table 2 has same three columns. here i have in Table 1 row 1 and 2, I have id as 5. but i see in row1 i have date as 1/1/2010 and row 2 has 2/2/2010. In the second table i have the same data but the dates are swapped between row 1 and 2 but same ID in row 1 and 2. I am not sure if i can still compare it by applying a common sort

Comment: in your table not a primary key! because id 5 has two record in join that differences is 'Change DETECTED' for both. this result has a problem for you?

Comment: if you want separate two records with id = 5 you can join two table with two condition. if you want this join let me edit my answer and add this to answer

Comment: i think this query work you fine and not a problem, because two record that changed and detected